# to_char in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am using `to_char` to `trim` the time part in date, when I am running below query in oracle it is showing right output that is skipping time span. but same when I am filling up in dataset and displaying in grid view time span also appears in output.

```
 StrSql.Append("select")
 StrSql.Append(" to_char(ABC.birth_date, 'DD/MM/yyyy') AS DOB,")
 StrSql.Append("from abc")
```

Can anyone please help me to come out with this issue????
I tried TRIM,TRUNC,TO_DATE but no use.

thax in advance.

Comment: More details is required - Which provider you are using?  Please post your database code fragment here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any SQL way, but you can try to get the data as-is and fetch it with VB.net's DateTime class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime.aspx#Y114).